# "He swept the floor with his jacket and lay down..." (Excerpted from "The Alchemist," by Paulo Coelho) is grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality

I am reading "The Alchemist," by Paulo Coelho. 
And I found a text like this: 
"He swept the floor with his jacket and lay down, using the book he had just finished reading as a pillow. He told himself that he would..."
As you can see, it is "lay down" instead of "laid down". So I would like to ask you guys for helps explaining more whether there is any other meaning for this one or whether I found it true that it is grammatically incorrect?

Thank you so much for your concerns.
Best regards.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inquiry of the usage of "laid down"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/258243/inquiry-of-the-usage-of-laid-down). There are two confusingly similar verbs: **_lie_**  I lie down // he lies down // I/he lay down // I have lain down //// **_lay_** I lay the book down // he lays the book down // I/he laid the book down // I have laid the book down.

Comment: Ohhhh, thank you so much, why I could forget that ^^
Lie --> lay --> lain
 / Lay --> laid --> laid